# Regression discontinuity - optimal bandwidth choice

Tags: poisson-regression, nonparametric, regression-discontinuity

I have a very basic question. I would like to implement a nonparametric RD but I have a Poisson outcome variable. I would like to select the proper bandwidth and my question is about which method to use, considering that this is not a classical linear regression case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is not a basic question (facing the same problem) as far as I know there is not a theoretical model that address this problem, there are some approximations like Xu(2018) and Xu(2017) for count data (with Matlab solutions). Another possible solution is cross validation (pre IK estimator).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I tried in Stata to write a cross-validation code based on Imbens and Lemieux (2008), but I was not able to replicate any other additional bandwidth. In the end, I decided to replace the Poisson with a dummy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in R from [Cattaneo, Idrobo, and Titiunik](https://www.cambridge.org/core/elements/abs/practical-introduction-to-regression-discontinuity-designs/F04907129D5C1B823E3DB19C31CAB905) that replicates [Ludwig and Miller](https://harris.uchicago.edu/files/inline-files/QJE_Headstart_2007_0.pdf) (2007)  CV BW estimator (the one that IK talked in their paper); for future endeavors, the link to the R package is [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rdrobust/rdrobust.pdf).